# How do I make an unweighted, undirected graph with string nodes in Rust?

Tags: rust, petgraph

I would like to create an unweighted, undirected graph with string nodes in Rust.  I've been trying to use `petgraph` and the `from_edges` construction method provided on `UnGraph`, but I am unable to do so because `&str` is not a valid NodeIndex.  Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: `GraphMap` in that same library might be what you're looking for, but you don't give us much to work with in this description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `HashMap` in where the *keys* are the nodes, and the *values* are a `Vec` of nodes connected to the key one. For convenience use `String` as the primary type for Nodes.
Also notice that the graph being undirected just means that you would need to add both nodes to the adjacent list. In the example fashion:

```
{
    "start": ["a", "b"],
    "a" : ["b", "d", "end"],
    "b": ["a", "end"],
    "d" : [],
    "end": []
}
```

```rust
type Graph = HashMap<String, Vec<String>>;

impl Graph {
   ...
}
```